# What are Whonix system requirements?

Tags: whonix

Hello my name is Gregory. I would like to ask a few questions about running Whonix on a notebook computer.

What would be an ideal notebook/specs for running

1. Linux Host
2. VirtualBox
3. Whonix (both VMs in VirtualBox)
4. VPN client on host

There has been alot of talk about Intel hardware having a backdoor in it. Obviously we can neither confirm/deny this information as we don't have access to it, we only have speculation but logically newer hardware would more likely have it since, unfortunately, we are going downhill when it comes to freedom and privacy.

So what would be an ideal notebook that is cheap and can run Whonix and everything on the notebook smoothly without lagging and glitches. We don't need to get specific about models, just specs and most importantly CPU models. RAM is cheap and upgradable so it is irrelevant as it would be 8GB. Would the CPU at least have to be an i3/i5/i7 model or can it be a late model Core 2 Duo? Again this is not a question of what can run this setup, it is what can run this setup very smoothly and without lagging.

mirimir has said in the past that SSDs can compromise FDE so my question goes out to mirimir and everybody else on that. Can SSD compromise FDE and why?

Answer (score 0):

Given OP's requirements, it's best to rely on the [hardware compatibility list for Qubes](http://wiki.qubes-os.org/trac/wiki/HCL). I say that for two reasons. First, Qubes developers are notoriously paranoid ;) Second, you would have the option of switching to Qubes.

Quad-core i5 with 8 GB RAM is fine. I'd avoid dual-core, especially old CPUs. But having enough RAM to avoid swapping is far more important for performance than CPU speed.

I still don't trust either hardware or software FDE on SSDs. The security of hardware FDE for consumer SSDs has generally relied on ATA passwords, and they can be readily compromised. Although enterprise SSDs and the new Crucial M500 line can be far more secure, using that capability involves (as far as I know) software that's only available in Windows. Faustian choice there :(

It's been claimed that, once dm-crypt/LUKS on has been configured on new SSDs, no plaintext will be written anywhere. However, I haven't seen corroboration from a source that I trust. Perhaps someone can enlighten us.

Comment: The hardware compatibility list has some Ivy Bridge and Sandy Bridge CPUs. I thought those were toxic now because of the Anti-Theft and vPro technology in them. There is no quad-core i5 mobile processor by the way.

Concerning FDE, that's what I ment, encryption through dm-crypt/LUKS. Is that considered secure even on SSDs? I know you mentioned that it's been claimed that nothing is out in the open but why are you so skeptical. Sorry for sounding ignorant as I don't understand why SSDs and HDDs are different when it comes to FDE. I'm guessing it has to do with the way they store information.

Comment: Although I've also been suspicious of the Anti-Theft and vPro features, discussion on Wilders convinced me that they're not an issue unless expressly implemented. Information storage in modern SSDs is highly abstracted from the hardware, far more so than in HDDs. And SSDs have tons (~30% as I recall) of hidden excess capacity, to increase lifetime. It's a big leap of faith for me to trust that no plaintext gets written while the volume is mounted.

Comment: Going back to system requirements for a second, Qubes OS obviously needs more hardware and more specific hardware considering their system is optimized for the listed models. Qubes is personally too much. How about Whonix though, is it still best to avoid the dual core notebook CPUs and also best to avoid anything Core 2 Duo so pretty much only Intel i Series CPUs? Obviously what I mean is a smooth running machine without lagging.

Comment: Qubes does have more specific hardware requirements. But it also has less overhead than Linux + VirtualBox + several VMs. Whonix is just two VMs. But maybe you'll want another workspace VM or two, maybe to use via VPN services, or maybe even a Windows VM. And you might want a few pfSense VMs as VPN and/or Tor gateways, and maybe even a JonDonym gateway. I'd stick with quad-core CPUs, which means i7 these days, I guess. But lower-end i7 is probably OK. Dual-core i5 would be enough for Whonix. But it would be CPU-bound if you ran 3-4 large VMs and a few small ones, which 8 GB RAM can handle.

Comment: The thing about quad-core notebook CPUs is that they have 4 cores and 8 threads but their clock speeds are kind of low and I don't have the budget for a 2nd/3rd/4th generation i7. The early quad-core i7s are 1.6-1.86GHz. Is that ok and can Debian use TurboBoost. I've seen some people clock their CPUs higher but that's on Windows with ThrottleStop to stop throttling but I haven't seen such application on Linux, is there? I do have a second question, is it better to connect the notebook directly into a modem via ethernet or better to put a DD-WRT router between the two?

Comment: For anonymity networks, "low latency" typically means at least hundreds of milliseconds. So there's not much point in blazing fast CPUs and overclocking. I've always used a router/firewall on my LAN. I'm currently using a low-end PC running pfSense. Also, keep in mind that iptables in Debian is by default wide open. You need to set DROP as default for INPUT, FORWARD and OUTPUT, and then add rules to allow only what's necessary (and to detect and block exploits on those rules).

Comment: So putting a DD-WRT router between the modem and the PC is a good setup? That way it's possible to run a VPN on it if you want to route traffic through a VPN. Does it add another attack surface though?

Comment: We're getting way off-topic for Tor.SE ;) But yes, that's possible. It adds a new player, the VPN provider. Now your ISP can see all the VPN traffic, but it's encrypted. And the VPN provider can see all of your Tor traffic with your entry guards, but that's all encrypted too. You can also add a perimeter router/firewall in your laptop as a pfSense or DD-Wrt VM, with its WAN bridged to the host NIC, and configure host iptables to restrict all traffic to it. And you can run a VPN on that VM, if you want. You can run several router VMs, each serving as a gateway, to Tor, JonDonym, a VPN, etc.

Comment: Sorry for getting a little off topic :) It's all part of the setup though. What I meant was the router itself, without a VPN even. Would a DD-WRT router add security between the modem and the PC or is it just useless and connecting to the modem directly via ethernet is better?

Comment: You always want the router/firewall. If nothing else, it keeps the ISP out of your LAN :)

Comment: May I ask what made you stop being suspicious of Intel's vPro/Identity Protection/Anti-Theft technology(s)? I now sort of understand what vPro is and maybe consider it less of a threat however what about the "Identity Protection" feature? It specifically states that it gives the computer a unique identity to "stop fraud and identity theft and such" but we all know the real reason. What about Anti-Theft, it works through internet it doesn't need a 3G connection. I really don't understand how these technologies work but I fear very much for their consequences on privacy/anonymity.

Comment: Read this thread: https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/secret-3g-intel-chip-provides-backdoors.353866/

Comment: That discussed didn't seem to come to a solid conclusion. It seems that there is still skepticism but cannot be proved/disproved on either side of the discussion. I am more interested in Anti-Theft and Identity Protection rather than vPro. Can it be confirmed that these technologies need to have proprietary drivers installed and also need to work on Windows and therefore would not even be able to work on Linux?

Comment: Continuation.... also I did some research and found an article that strongly condemns the additions and calls them exploits and backdoors. However it did say that Windows is part of the weak link and that these technologies are optimized for Windows. It also says that even though Linux is getting proprietary drivers from Intel now they are quest additions and need to be installed by the user and can therefore be avoided, just like graphic card drivers and other closed source code. http://semiaccurate.com/2012/05/15/intel-small-business-advantage-is-a-security-nightmare/

Comment: @GregoryYelkovic Good article! So as long as one avoids Windows and proprietary drivers, risk seems minimal. One could ask Invisible Things Lab about this, I suppose. Would they include dangerous hardware on their HCL?

Comment: What is your opinion on the new UEFI systems replacing BIOS and making it harder to run Linux on newer hardware. I have also tried to find out how to put Linux/Debian directly on a MacBook Pro but it seems like a very difficult and "buggy". Some people also say to avoid Apple's UEFI as it may be backdoored. What do you think?

Comment: These would be good questions for Unix/Linux.SE, or even for Wilders. It's my impression that Linux with UEFI is secure. I know nothing about Apple hardware.

Comment: So back to system requirements, assuming only Whonix will be run on the machine with a Debian host and a VPN on host as well as firewall rules, would a Core 2 Duo 2.53GHz with 8GB ram be smooth and fast?

Comment: It's borderline. With two cores, there may be some CPU contention when the host and two VMs are doing something simultaneously. But in the context of using Tor, that shouldn't be a major issue.